# Has Opigno similar API features as moodle?

Tags: moodle, lms

I am currently evaluating opigno because we want to switch from moodle to this LMS.

As we use the API to create users I want to ask if the following features are included to be called from the API:

1. Create and delete Users
2. Create classes / course groups
3. Subscribe a user to a course (enrolment)

The documentation is not very helpful at this point.
Apart from that is it possible to set the duration for a enrolment e.g. from May 1st 2023 until December 31st 2023 so that the access to that course is not possible after that date?

Thanks and regards Matt